# Iterator<T> в классе Stack<T>

Tags: java

Сделал обобщенный класс Stack. Нужно написать класс итератор, но я не понимаю, как он должен работать. Извлекать данные из стека при каждом вызове next() или неизменяя стека выводить данные?
После прохода итератором должен остаться пустой стек или нетронутый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оставить нетронутым. Итераторы созданы для получения информации из контейнера, а не для его изменения.
Однако, это лишь "правильный" способ, реализовать можно как угодно, вопрос лишь в разумности.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, с реализацией разберусь.